# Exception when creating a list saying:

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
        try
        {
            var result =
           from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
           let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
           let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
           let notes = properties.Element(d + "DetailsJSON")
           let questionMessage = properties.Element(d + "QuestionText")
           let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
           let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
           where partitionKey.Value == "0001I" && title != null
           select new Question
           {
               Notes = notes.Value ?? "n/a",
               Title = title.Value,
               QuestionMessage = questionMessage.Value
           };

            // xx
            IList<Question> resultx = null;
            foreach (var question in result)
            {
                resultx.Add(question);
            }
            // yy
            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("GetQuestions.Get problem", ex);
        };
```

If I comment out the part of the code between xx and yy then it works. Otherwise I get an exception saying:

```
ex  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
```

Can someone give me some ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is `null`, hence the `NullReferenceException`:

```
IList<Question> resultx = null;
foreach (var question in result)
{
    resultx.Add(question); // Ouch. resultx is set to null above here
}
```

You need to initialize the list to actually be a `List<Question>`, not `null`:

```
IList<Question resultx = new List<Question>();
// .. the rest of the code
```

Comment: 119WPM with 0 errors... (we had a competition at work the other day) :)

Comment: Coding for 9 years and still only use 3-4 fingers to type

Answer (score 1):

Your `resultx` is explicitly set to null, so upon `resultx.Add()` you get a `NullReferenceException`. You need to initialize the list first.